# GraphAssortativity returns Indeterminate outcome

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am relatively new to Mathematica. Possibly, this is a very banal question. I want to use the function

```
GraphAssortativity[g,"VertexColors"]
```

function for a directed network "g" I have generated but I obtain

```
Divide::indet: Indeterminate expression 0./0. encountered.
```

The network "g" is generated as

```
IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[A, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> imsize, VertexSize -> 0.3, 
 VertexStyle -> 
  Flatten[Table[
    k -> Which[col[A][[k]]^0.2 >= 0.7, Black, col[A][[k]]^0.2 <= 0.3, 
      White, 0.3 < col[A][[k]]^0.2 < 0.7, Gray], {k, 1, 10}]]]
```

where adjacency matrix "A" is a result of a recursive algorithm and col[A]:= A.b with "b" a vector.

I guess the problem is on the vertex coloring (VertexStyle) but I cannot figure out where exactly.

The network "g" is connected.

Example:

Consider the matrix

```
    X={{0., 0., 0., 0.714286, 0., 0.285714, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.5, 
  0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.}, {0.290323, 0., 0.0645161, 0., 0., 
  0.0645161, 0.290323, 0., 0., 0.290323}, {0.225, 0.05, 0.05, 0., 
  0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.357143, 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0.642857, 0.}, {0., 0.181818, 0., 0.454545, 0., 0., 0.181818, 
  0.181818, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.227273, 0.227273, 0.0909091, 0., 0., 0., 
  0.227273, 0., 0.227273}, {0., 0.263158, 0., 0.473684, 0.263158, 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0.117647, 0., 0.117647, 0., 0., 0.117647, 0., 
  0.529412, 0., 0.117647}, {0.25, 0.45, 0.1, 0., 0.1, 0., 0., 0.1, 0.,
   0.}}
```

and vector

```
b0 = {{0}, {0.5}, {0.7}, {0.4}, {0.3}, {0.2}, {0.8}, {0.9}, {0.1},
{1}};
```

Define and calculate

```
col[X_] := Flatten[X.b0]
g = IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[X, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 200, VertexSize -> 0.3, 
  VertexStyle -> 
   Flatten[Table[
     k -> RGBColor[col[X][[k]], col[X][[k]], col[X][[k]]], {k, 1, 
      10}]]]
```

I would like to calculate the homophily/graph assortativity measure based on vertex colors

Comment: Is your graph connected? Try `ConnectedGraphQ[g]`.

Comment: This graph does not have a property called "VertexColors".  Can you show a complete minimal example?

Comment: @flinty Why does it matter if it is connected?

Comment: What do you mean by "based on vertex colours"? In what way do you want to take colours into account? Note that there is no property called "VertexColors". See the Details section of the reference page for what GraphAssortativity actually computes. There are two definitions, one for numerical and one for categorical data. Which one do you need? Do you want to use the numbers returned by `col[X]` as numbers, or do you want to check when two vertices have the "same colour"?

Comment: The reason why you see the error is that you pass in a non-existent property. Mathematica interprets it as "categorical" and takes each vertex to have the same category ("nothing"), which leads to 0/0.

Comment: @Szabolcs turns out it doesn't matter `GraphAssortativity[DirectedGraph@AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]]` - works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the colours you need `VertexStyle` not the string `"VertexColors"`

```
AnnotationValue[{g, 2}, "VertexColors"]
(* returns a $Failed *)

AnnotationValue[{g, 2}, VertexStyle]
(* returns a color *)

GraphAssortativity[g, VertexStyle]
(* returns -0.11111 *)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me from the question that this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much Szabolcs and flinty. This clarifies a lot. I wanted to use the numbers returned by col[X] as numbers and compute the relative assortativity measure. Sorry for the confusion. I have used the expression "same color" since I have mapped col[X] to colors.